# When I run the "ometpp.ini" file, the simulation prompts:

Tags: omnet++

illegal character " " encountered in tag name while parsing display string "i=block/routing" -- at t=0s,envent #0
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHR8P.png)

Part of the code is as follows:

```
simple nodeR
{
    parameters:
        @display("i = block/routing");
        @signal[arrival](type="long");
        @statistic[hopCount](title="hop count"; source="arrival"; record=vector,stats; interpolationmode=none);
    gates:
        inout gate[];
}
```

How should I do it? Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is clear: do NOT add space after the *i* tag. i.e. between *i* and *=*.